# How to edit id code value in php

Tags: php

I am using the code bellow in a formmail. But i want to change the code, so user input can be both numbers and letter and others, and so it can be any lenght. Hope someone can help with the 2 changes. Thanks.

```
if(isset($_POST['idcode'])) {

    if(strlen($_POST['idcode']) != 8 || !is_numeric($_POST['idcode'])) {

        $error = "input must contain 8 numbers";

    } else {
```

Comment: Just remove your `if` then, what else?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it accepts everything do this:

```
if(isset($_POST['idcode'])) {
// code here

} else {
    $error = "you must set the idcode"; // can be changed
}
```

But if you want to check for length of 8 and up do this:

```
if(isset($_POST['idcode'])) {
    if(strlen($_POST['idcode']) >= 8) {
        // code here
    } else {
       $error = "you need to have at least 8 chars"; // can change
    }
} else {
    $error = "you must set the idcode"; // can be changed
}
```